# How can I display a "Pause Icon" when user clicks on a playing video in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, controller, video-player

I use the following code to show a video to user and give them ability to pause, replay the video:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class BasicOverlayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController? controller;
  const BasicOverlayWidget({
    Key? key,
    @override this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () => controller!.value.isPlaying
          ? controller!.pause()
          : controller!.play(),
      child: Stack(children: [
        buildPlay(),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: buildIndicator(),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget buildIndicator() =>
      VideoProgressIndicator(controller!, allowScrubbing: true);

  Widget buildPlay() => controller!.value.isPlaying
      ? Container()
      : Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.black26,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.black26,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.play_arrow,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 80,
            ),
          ),
        );
}
```

What I am trying to do is when user taps on a video that is already playing, show a pause Icon for half a second, then show the play button until the user taps again and video starts again and the play button disappears( something like what every video players do).

The above code does the second job well, but I don't know how to show a pause icon for half a second, then pause the video and show play icon?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'basic_overlay_widget.dart';

class VideoPlayerBaseWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController? controller;

  const VideoPlayerBaseWidget({
    Key? key,
    @override this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return controller != null && controller!.value.isInitialized
        ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: buildVideo(),
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            height: 200,
            child: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
  }

  Widget buildVideo() => Stack(children: [
        buildVideoPlayer(),
        Positioned.fill(child: BasicOverlayWidget(controller: controller)),
      ]);
  Widget buildVideoPlayer() => VideoPlayer(controller!);
}
```

Comment: can you include your video-controller and how you are using `BasicOverlayWidget `

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: I added it at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a listener to the videoController.

I am using `StatefulWidget` with nullable bool to control the icon/state.

```dart
class BasicOverlayWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController? controller;
  const BasicOverlayWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BasicOverlayWidget> createState() => _BasicOverlayWidgetState();
}

class _BasicOverlayWidgetState extends State<BasicOverlayWidget> {
  bool? isPlaying;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.controller != null) {
      widget.controller?.addListener(() async {
        if (widget.controller!.value.isPlaying == true && isPlaying == null) {
          setState(() {
            isPlaying = true;
          });
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
          setState(() {
            isPlaying = false;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
  // dispose the controller 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () => isPlaying ?? false
          ? widget.controller!.pause()
          : widget.controller!.play(),
      child: Stack(children: [
        buildPlay(),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: buildIndicator(),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget buildIndicator() =>
      VideoProgressIndicator(widget.controller!, allowScrubbing: true);

  Widget buildPlay() => isPlaying ?? false
      ? Center(
          child: Icon(
          Icons.pause,
          size: 33,
        ))
      : Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.black26,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.black26,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.play_arrow,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 80,
            ),
          ),
        );
}
```

---

tested snippet

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => FavFood(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: VideoPlayerBaseWidget(
            controller: _controller,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerBaseWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController? controller;

  const VideoPlayerBaseWidget({
    Key? key,
    @override this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return controller != null && controller!.value.isInitialized
        ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: buildVideo(),
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            height: 200,
            child: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
  }

  Widget buildVideo() => Stack(children: [
        buildVideoPlayer(),
        Positioned.fill(child: BasicOverlayWidget(controller: controller)),
      ]);
  Widget buildVideoPlayer() => VideoPlayer(controller!);
}

class BasicOverlayWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController? controller;
  const BasicOverlayWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BasicOverlayWidget> createState() => _BasicOverlayWidgetState();
}

class _BasicOverlayWidgetState extends State<BasicOverlayWidget> {
  bool? isPlaying;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.controller != null) {
      widget.controller?.addListener(() async {
        if (widget.controller!.value.isPlaying == true && isPlaying == null) {
          setState(() {
            isPlaying = true;
          });
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
          setState(() {
            isPlaying = false;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () => isPlaying ?? false
          ? widget.controller!.pause()
          : widget.controller!.play(),
      child: Stack(children: [
        buildPlay(),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: buildIndicator(),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget buildIndicator() =>
      VideoProgressIndicator(widget.controller!, allowScrubbing: true);

  Widget buildPlay() => isPlaying ?? false
      ? Center(
          child: Icon(
          Icons.pause,
          size: 33,
        ))
      : Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.black26,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.black26,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.play_arrow,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 80,
            ),
          ),
        );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work!

Comment: Can you try flutter clean and rebuild the app, there is a small icon will show middle of the screen

Comment: I did `flutter clean` and tried it again, same as before!

Comment: Ok I am sharing the full snippet and tested on chrome